# Many models with one dynamic mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am planning a new mvc 3 application.

I am trying to make things as simple as possible.

Here's my question.

I'm planning on having many different models with different params. I am going to have crud operations for all these models but I don't want to have a view for each one. I would like to have one list view and one edit view.

I know this goes agains the lose coupled style of mvc architecture but It would be very handy just for me to send the view a model and the view would work out what fields to add etc.

Has anyone heard o a way to do this?

Comment: Imagine how bloated the view is going to get. An what the debugging will be like? I smell trouble.

Comment: Would the view get bloated? I will only ever have dynamically generated HTML and a dynamic model. But saying that I know you cant do lambda expressions on dynamic models. Hmm this may not be possible

Answer (score 0):

MVC has an `Html.EditorFor()` helper into which you can give a whole model and MVC will generate a form from it. I have not tried whether this works dynamicly when your view's model is type of object and you give concrete objects into it, but it might work.

But for all those headaches you will have in the future with your approach I would strongly suggest for you to try to make your different models into an object hierachy (so you will have inherintance) and compose your views with different partial views based on the model's type.
I have used the last way of doing things sucessfully on many occasions. Something in the lines of (code in your topmost view):

```
@model Animal

//Show Animal fields

@if(Model is Cat)
{
    //show cat specific fields
    Html.Partial("_cat", Model);
}
else if(Model is Dog)
{
    //show dog specific fields
    Html.Partial("_dog", Model);
}
```

So in your controller you could pass either a Dog, Cat or Animal to this view and what would be rendered is dependent on the Model's type.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just implemented an existing MVC feature! Instead of if-ing all the models, just add @model directive to your views and voila!

Comment: Ok, how is that different?

Comment: With this solution you can have visual inheritance with polymorphic views. If ASP.NET MVC actually has different kind of support for this, please educate me.

Comment: Look, the way you have coded it there is no difference between that and strongly typed views. You have to add some rendering from your base class to show what you want to show.